# Using overflow hidden while aligning the contents the bottom right of a div?

Tags: html, css, overflow, positioning

I have a div at 200px wide x 150px height. The image in the div will be bigger. I want to align the image inside to the bottom right corner while using the overflow hidden setting on the rest of the image. So only the bottom right corner of the image should be visible.

I can't figure out how to use relative positioning in this case because there will be different sized images in the div. I need whatever image is in the div to automatically lock alignment to the bottom right regardless of size. Is this possible?

Here's my code:

```html
<div align="right" valign="bottom" style="width:200px; height:105px; border: 1px dotted black; overflow: hidden;">
  <div style="position:relative; bottom:0px; right:0px;">
    <img src="https://www.catster.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/A-fluffy-cat-looking-funny-surprised-or-concerned.jpg" width="300" height="300" />
  </div>
</div>
```

For the example I have the image set to 500x300px but in the finished product this will be pulling in different images.

Comment: It's not possible with relative positioning.  You'd need to use absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it using position relative to the image.

But you can use the `relative` and `absolute` together.

If the parent has the `position: relative` and the child has the `position: absolute`, the child will use the parent's area as limits to self positioning

Try this:

```html
<div align="right" valign="bottom" style="width:200px; height:105px; border: 1px dotted black; overflow: hidden; position: relative">
    <div style="position:absolute; bottom:0px; right:0px;" >
        <img src="https://www.catster.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/A-fluffy-cat-looking-funny-surprised-or-concerned.jpg" width="300" height="300"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to position an element relatively to its parent, you need first to set `position: relative` on the parent container.

HTML File :

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <img src="https://www.catster.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/A-fluffy-cat-looking-funny-surprised-or-concerned.jpg" width="300"
        height="300" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS File :

```
.outer {
    width: 200px;
    height: 105px;
    border: 1px dotted black;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.inner {
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0px; 
    right: 0px;
}
```

I've provided a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sL6vwkg9/4) to help you with that.

Hope that helps!

Comment: You need to put your code in your question, not a third-party site